# How do you change the hardware version for the device testing and the device on Xcode 4.2 through the iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

I am trying to figure out how to change the hardware version and the device itself through the simulator on Xcode. Ever since downloading the new version of Xcode I don't have access to 5.0 software and so it is hard to continue on previous work whilst adapting to iOS 6. Does anyone know how to find and download it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Xcode ->Preferences->Downloads->Components. 
There you can download previous simulators